# parse syslog message through sscanf

Tags: c, syslog, scanf

I got a `syslog` message

```
<14>2012-04-19T03:54:18+08:00.527800 server3000 status: 00|00|The average CPU, memory, disk usage and total network flow are 5.0%, 5.0%, 5.0% and 5 bytes respectively for the last hour.\n
```

How can I get the word `2012-04-19,03:54:18+08:00.527800,server3000,status,00,00 and 5.0` through the function `sscanf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int t1,t2 = 0;
char programname[20], deviceip[16], date[11], time[9];
char logmsg[30];
const char * s = "<14>2012-04-19T03:54:18.527800+08:00 server3000 status: 00|00|The average CPU, memory, disk usage and total network flow are 5.0%, 5.0%, 5.0% and 5 bytes respectively for the last hour";
sscanf(s, "<%*d>%[^T]T%[^.].%*[^ ] %[^ ] %[^:]: %d|%d|%[^\n]", date, time,deviceip, programname, &t1, &t2, logmsg);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like to save the result of `sscanf` and check its value:

```
int rc = sscanf(...);
if(rc < 7)
    // failed to match or extract
```

`sscanf` in your code returns 7, meaning that your format string matched and extracted all 7 arguments.